# How to Conceal My actual video streaming server from users in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, video-streaming, reverse-proxy

I am working on a VoD project in NodeJS which must provide customers with some videos to buy or subscribe.

Video are hosted on a Streaming Server (a server like Red5, but not exactly Red5) and provides interactive player, adaptive bit-rate streaming, enhanced speed using CDN, and etc.

The problem I have is users are able to download the video seeing they easily obtain videos URL.

According to the below question:

[Is there a way a video file on a remote server can be downloaded in chunks using Node.js and piped through to a client, without storing any data on the server, …?](https://www.reddit.com/r/node/comments/3degp9/a_question_about_video_streaming_using_nodejs/)

[Request NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) has been suggested.

Now my questions are:

1. Is the suggested solution a wise decision to adapt for my scenario?
2. Following suggested solution would it be possible to use server's provided features like adaptive bit-rate streaming, ...?

Answer (score 0):

You may also encrypt each segment with AES to prevent copy.

Comment: Questions are:

1. Is Request NPM has been suggested solution a wise decision to adapt for my scenario?
2. Following Request NPM solution would it be possible to use server's provided features like adaptive bit-rate streaming, ...?